# mac m1 12.4 with brew arm and x86 versions installed, how do I uninstall the x86 brew

Tags: macos, x86, homebrew, uninstallation, silicon

I have a new mac m1 os version 12.4 and
Installed brew and later installed
the x86 version with
arch -x86_64 /bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install.sh)"

I'd like to remove the x86 version.
From what I have read I should be able to uninstall it with

```bash
 arch -x86_64 /bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/uninstall.sh)"
```

This prints

```bash
$ arch -x86_64 /bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/uninstall.sh)"

Warning: This script will remove:
    /opt/homebrew/.dockerignore
    /opt/homebrew/.editorconfig
    /opt/homebrew/.git/
    /opt/homebrew/.github/
    /opt/homebrew/.gitignore
    /opt/homebrew/.shellcheckrc
    /opt/homebrew/.sublime/
    /opt/homebrew/.vale.ini
    /opt/homebrew/.vscode/
    /opt/homebrew/CHANGELOG.md
    /opt/homebrew/CONTRIBUTING.md
    /opt/homebrew/Caskroom/
    /opt/homebrew/Cellar/
    /opt/homebrew/Dockerfile
    /opt/homebrew/LICENSE.txt
    /opt/homebrew/Library//
    /opt/homebrew/README.md
    /opt/homebrew/bin/brew
    /opt/homebrew/completions/
    /opt/homebrew/docs/
    /opt/homebrew/manpages/
    Are you sure you want to uninstall Homebrew? This will remove your installed packages! [y/N] N
```

This is the arm version. It should be removing it from /usr/local/bin.
How do I remove it?

Answer (score 2):

The solution is to run the uninstall with
--path=/usr/local